# capybara feature spec hover+click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using rspec + capybara + poltergeist. When I try to simulate hover then click on an element I get an error. Problem should be with using them together since when I delete the click from behind the hover it doesn't throw any error.

How can I make this work?

```
scenario "successfully", js: true do
  sign_in(user)
  visit root_path
  within "#postcomment-#{post_comment.id}" do
    page.find(".post-comment-body").hover.find("#activate-comment-edit-#{post_comment.id}").click
  end
  ....


error:
1) updating post successfully
 Failure/Error: page.find(".post-comment-body").hover.find("#activate-comment-edit-#{post_comment.id}").click

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `click' for #<Enumerator:0x007fe255dd4b10>
```

Comment: You have to make separate call for both. I mean hover and click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#hover` does not return the element it was called on.  Because of this you can either store the element you find like

```
within "#postcomment-#{post_comment.id}" do
  body = page.find(".post-comment-body")
  body.hover
  body.find("#activate-comment-edit-#{post_comment.id}").click
end
```

or to keep it one line

```
within "#postcomment-#{post_comment.id}" do
  page.find(".post-comment-body").tap(&:hover).find("#activate-comment-edit-#{post_comment.id}").click
end
```